# display page number on UIToolbar at bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitoolbar

If i have to display page number as title on uitoolbar at the bottom like this

```
_toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 960, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];


_title1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %u", currentIndex]
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:nil
                                          action:nil];
```

Then is it possible to update page number on UIToolbar when page is turned over

Comment: Yes it is possible. What is your actual question? Do you need help updating `currentIndex` as each page is turned? Or do you not know how to update the toolbar each time `currentIndex` is updated?

Comment: How to update toolbar each time current index is updated.

Comment: You need to recreate the toolbar items with the updated details. You can't simply update the existing item with the page number.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a delegate system using protocols.